# Can an iOS app put the Apple Watch in airplane mode programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, airplane-mode

Can an iOS app programmatically put the Apple Watch in and out of airplane mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it can't.

Even if it could put it in airplane mode, it couldn't take it out of airplane mode since it would no longer be able to communicate with the watch, since the watch would be in airplane mode.

Comment: The watch need to communicate with the phone via Bluetooth or via wifi (if the phone is too far away for Bluetooth). If the watch radios are off then it can't use either of these methods to communicate with the iOS device.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, Paul. How about an app running on the iwatch? Will it be able to turn off bluetooth or wifi or both on the iwatch? If yes, can you please let me know how to do the same? Thanks again

Comment: No. In general apps can not control any device settings on either the watch or the phone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helpful reply, Paul